# YouTube Live Chat embed now working on non-www website

Tags: javascript, youtube, embed

I have code that embeds a live YouTube chat into my website. It works flawlessly on one of my website with a www in the domain. However when using the same code on a different website without the www, it doesn't work.

Code:

```
<iframe
src="https://youtube.com/live_chat?v=sca81R6Ar4I&embed_domain=example.org"
frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
>
</iframe>
```

This works flawlessly if the code looks like this:

```
<iframe
src="https://youtube.com/live_chat?v=sca81R6Ar4I&embed_domain=www.example.org"
frameborder="0"
allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Does your website only allow traffic on the `www.` subdomain?

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Dear without www it's can't access your website you have to use www

Comment: This blog may helps you https://www.peggyktc.com/2016/05/embed-livestream-and-chat.html?m=1

Comment: Sadly, there is only one person with the www issue, and no fix.